# I need help understanding javascript animation

Tags: javascript

I'm new to HTML and javascript and in the last few weeks I tried to do a little personal project.
Basically it is a login page with an eye that follows your cursor while writing the email and closes when you are writing the password. If the user wishes to see the password, then three little eyes open.

Having successfully done this I wanted to add a blinking animation. It crashed my web page entirely. Searching online and asking chatGPT I was able to resolve part of the problem and right now the animation is pre-loaded so that it doesn't weight down on the page.

However, since at every time there is one full cycle of animation loaded, even in the "states" in which there is to be no animation (for example when the user enters the email), one full cycle is done before stopping.

Since I'm just starting I understand that the problem originates from the animation being preloaded, but I don't really know how to change my code in order for it to work.

I attach my [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/Gin42/horror-login-form) and my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Random-Stuff-the-animator/pen/XWQRjeV).

EXPECTED BEHAVIOUR:

- When the windows first opens the only animation that should be present is of the blinking of the big eye. This blinking follows a random time and goes on forever is nothing happens.
- When the user enters their email the pupil should move following the writing. The blinking should stop the moment the input box is clicked and should remain as such until the input box is still in focus.
- When the user enters their password the big eye should close. The blinking should stop the moment the input box is clicked and should remain as such until the input box is still in focus.
- When the "Password visible" icon is clicked the password should turn visible and, while the big eye is still closed, three little eyes, located at the center of the three tears, should open and start blinking. If the "Password visible" icon is clicked again, the password turns invisible and the little eyes should disappear.
- The eye remains closed until the login button is clicked or the user enters their email again.

CURRENT BEHAVIOUR:

- When the user enters their email the pupil should move follows the writing. The eye blinks one more time before laying still.
- When the user enters their password the big eye should close. If the animation had time to load, the eye blinks one more time before laying still.
- When the "Password visible" icon is clicked the three little eyes open and start blinking, but if the "Password visible" icon is clicked again, they disappear but return after a while.

Here's the code of the two functions that orders the pre-load of the animation.
Blinking is used to set the behaviour of the bigger eye, while sblinking is for the three smaller eyes.

```
function blinking() {
  function animate() {
    if (i === -1) {
      updateFrame(1);
    }
    if (!input) {
      const delayInSeconds =
        Math.floor(Math.random() * DELAY_RANGE) + DELAY_MIN;
      const delayInMilliseconds = delayInSeconds * 1000;
      // Use setTimeout to schedule closeLid after a delay
      setTimeout(closeLid, delayInMilliseconds);
      // Stop the animation loop
      return;
    }
    // Request the next animation frame
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }

  // Start the animation loop
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

```
function sblinking() {
  function sanimate() {
    if (currentFrame === -1) {
      updateMask(1);
    }
  }
  if(passInput.type === "text") {
      const delayInSeconds = Math.floor(Math.random() * DELAY_RANGE) + DELAY_MIN;
      const delayInMilliseconds = delayInSeconds * 1000;
      setTimeout(closeSLid, delayInMilliseconds);
      requestAnimationFrame(sanimate);
  }
  // Start the animation loop
    requestAnimationFrame(sanimate);
}
```